# Почему возникает Segmentation fault при установке значения свойства в Qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, segmentation-fault

Добавляю круговую диаграмму в форме Qt. Создание QChartView вынес в отдельную функцию, которая возвращает указатель на QChartView:

```
QChartView* DiagramForm::createPie(QWidget *parent) {

    QPieSeries *series = new QPieSeries();

    QChart *chart = new QChart();
    chart->addSeries(series);
    chart->setTitle("SQL Piechart");

    QChartView *chartView = new QChartView(chart);
    chartView->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

    parent->setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
    chartView->setParent(parent);

    return chartView;

}
```

При использовании такого вызова все в порядке, программа работает:

```
QChartView *cw = this->createView(parent);
```

Однако если я в заголовочном файле объявлю приватное свойство:

```
QChartView *cw;
```

А потом вызову функцию так:

```
this->cw = this->createView(parent);
```

То возникает ошибка segfault. В чем причина? Как ни крути, но ведь нигде нет вызова "чужой" памяти.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй просто так: *cw = this->createView(parent);